# How to remove a html tag and only echo the text inside it?

Tags: php

I have a php code which echos a html element:

```
<?php echo the_content(); ?>
```

It's resulting in:

```
<p>MY CUSTOM TEXT FROM ANOTHER PAGE INSIDE MY SITE</p>
```

How can I remove the `<p>` & `</p>` from the result?

I don't want to manually remove the tags `<p>` & `</p>` from the page it's coming from, because it is also used in another page in html.

## ***Edited**

I'm currently trying this: *But it's not working...

```
$content = the_content();
echo strip_tags($content);
```

and

```
$content = the_content();
$content = strip_tags($content);
echo ($content);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/iwBSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it to work with this:

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 160) . '...'; ?>
```

Probably I was using the element `the_content()` from wordpress which includes automatically an HTML element `<p>` & `</p>` for the front-end page, with `post_content` it gets the inner content from the post without the f*cking `<p>` & `</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
<?php echo strip_tags(the_content()); ?>
```

Also:

```
<?= strip_tags(the_content()) ?>
```

Comment: I tried both, it's not working. I'm still trying at the moment,.

Comment: Please check my question again, I've updated it.

Comment: @asdaqwr14241adadad214fvagsdg as long as `the_content()` returns something, the code you're using will work.

Comment: `the_content()` is from wordpress, may it not work because of that?

Comment: Do a `echo the_content()` and see if it outputs anything

Comment: the echo works of course, I've checked it before, but it is included with a `<p>` & `</p>` which I don't want to.

Comment: My friend this is impossible. Check it now. If your function returns content, strip tags will remove tags. Your error is elsewhere

Comment: Can I use for this `$_POST` to get the `the_content()` then strip_tag it?

Comment: Finally! I fixed with this: `echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 160) . '...';`